# How to define custom cost function that depends on input when using ImageDataGenerator in Keras?

Tags: keras

I would like to define a custom cost function

```
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    ....
    return L
```

that will depend not only on `y_true` and `y_pred`, but on some feature of the corresponding `x` that produced `y_pred`. The only way I can think of doing this is to "hide" the relevant features in `y_true`, so that `y_true = [usual_y_true, relevant_x_features]`, or something like that.

There are two main problems I am having with implementing this:

1) Changing the shape of `y_true` means I need to pad `y_pred` with some garbage so that their shapes are the same. I can do this by modyfing the last layer of my model

2) I used data augmentation like so:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=my_augmenter)
```

where `my_augmenter()` is the function that should also give me the relevant `x` features to use in `custom_objective()` above. However, training with

```
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1), ...)
```

doesn't seem to give me access to the features calculated with `my_augmenter`.

I suppose I could hide the features in the augmented `x_train`, copy them right away in my model setup, and then feed them directly into `y_true` or something like that, but surely there must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858016/keras-custom-loss-function-to-pass-arguments-other-than-y-true-and-y-pred).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could create a two part model with:

- Inner model: original model that predicts desired outputs
- Outer model:

  - Takes y_true data as inputs
  - Takes features as inputs
  - Outputs the loss itself (instead of predicted data)

So, suppose you already have the `originalModel` defined. Let's define the outer model.

```py
#this model has three inputs:
originalInputs = originalModel.input  
yTrueInputs = Input(shape_of_y_train)
featureInputs = Input(shape_of_features)

#the original outputs will become an input for a custom loss layer
originalOutputs = originalModel.output

#this layer contains our custom loss
loss = Lambda(innerLoss)([originalOutputs, yTrueInputs, featureInputs])

#outer model
outerModel = Model([originalInputs, yTrueInputs, featureInputs], loss)
```

Now, our custom inner loss:

```
def innerLoss(x):
    y_pred = x[0] 
    y_true = x[1]
    features = x[2] 

    .... calculate and return loss here ....
```

Now, for this model that already contains a custom loss "inside" it, we don't actually want a final loss function, but since keras demands it, we will use the final loss as just `return y_pred`:

```
def finalLoss(true,pred):
    return pred
```

This will allow us to train passing just a dummy `y_true`.

---

But of course, we also need a custom generator, otherwise we can't get the features.

Consider you already have `originalGenerator =datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1)` defined:

```py
def customGenerator(originalGenerator):

    while True: #keras needs infinite generators
        x, y = next(originalGenerator)

        features = ____extract features here____(x)

        yield (x,y,features), y 
            #the last y will be a dummy output, necessary but not used
```

You could also, if you want the extra functionality of randomizing batch order and use multiprocessing, implement a `class CustomGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence)` following the same logic. The [help page](https://keras.io/utils/) shows how.

So, let's compile and train the outer model (this also trains the inner model so you can use it later for predicting):

```py
outerModel.compile(optimizer=..., loss=finalLoss)
outerModel.fit_generator(customGenerator(originalGenerator), batchesInOriginalGenerator, 
                         epochs=...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm trying to wrap my head around all of it... I'm currently getting an error with `loss = Lambda(innerLoss)([originalOutputs, yTrueInputs, featureInputs])` saying "Layer lambda_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor."

Comment: Something in the list is not a tensor. If you followed my code exactly, that should not happen. Pay attention to the lines `originalModel.outputs`.

Comment: Does the original model have multiple outputs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "multiple", but the original model outputs an image (it's an autoencoder). The final layer is `decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)`.

Comment: Here's the full error: `Layer lambda_2 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'list'>. Full input: [[<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_3/Sigmoid:0' shape=(?, 136, 136, 1) dtype=float32>], <tf.Tensor 'input_10:0' shape=(?, 3410, 136, 136, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_11:0' shape=(?, 1, 1) dtype=float32>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`

Comment: Interesting, the output of the original model came as a list of one tensor. This usually doesn't happen to me, maybe it's a matter of different keras versions. Use `originalModel.output` instead. If nothing works: `originalOutputs = originalModel(Input(input_shape))`