# How to update the weights in Kera

Tags: keras

I'm trying to update a LSTM's weights written in Keras based on a self-defined loss function. I found pytorch has a function `torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())` able to do that. Is there any one like this in keras? Or any good approach with keras can update weights regarding the batch gradient descent on a loss function?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858016/keras-custom-loss-function-to-pass-arguments-other-than-y-true-and-y-pred what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, @MarkLoyman! I wasn't clear about my question above. The loss function I defined contains other reward values beside the predict_y and actual_y, eventually, I figured out that I have to use the Keras backend function or tensorflow directly.